# Text Extraction from a folder having multiple images to CSV

Tags: python, csv, image-processing

I have a file having multiple images and I want to extract the text from them and then to store it in CSV . I tried but not getting satisfied result.
this is my code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az13Q.jpg)

```html
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import pytesseract
import os

#Define path to tessaract.exe
path_to_tesseract = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

#Define path to image
path_to_images = r'all_img_iteration_demo/'

#Point tessaract_cmd to tessaract.exe
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract

#Get the file names in the directory
for root, dirs, file_names in os.walk(path_to_images):
    #Iterate over each file_name in the folder
    for file_name in file_names:
        #Open image with PIL
        img = Image.open(path_to_images + file_name)

        #Extract text from image
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)        
        list_1 = text.split()             
        print(list_1)
        jdemo = "datarecords.csv"
        with open(jdemo, 'w') as csvfile:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
            csvwriter.writerow(list_1)
```

this is the output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heKi6.jpg)
what i am getting right now is is this..

i tried to store the extracted text to csv but only last value i am getting in the file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6oKJ.jpg)

i want output of each extracted text into new row of csv file . and then iterate over next image and so on..

Comment: You can try out the tabula or Camelot if it is a table. Or else just for text extraction, you can use paddle OCR which gives you good results than tesseract.  And aslo, Can you paste the code instead of attaching the photo. It will be helpful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.